# Uncaught ReferenceError: Operadores_lst is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

Good afternoon all i have a little problem. Im creating this function on JS to create a  search filter. This is the JS code for the filter. Sorry but the code is in Spanish.

```
function FiltrarOperador() {
var filtro = $("#txtFiltroOperador").val().toUpperCase();
if (filtro == "") {
    LlenarCombo({ Combo: "cboOperador", Resultado: Operadores_lst, CampoId: "idOperador", CampoValor: "Nombre", TextoNull: Recursos["NotAny"] });
} else {
    LlenarCombo({ Combo: "cboOperador", Resultado: Operadores_lst.where(function (a) { return a.Nombre.toUpperCase().indexOf(filtro) != -1; }), CampoId: "id", CampoValor: "Nombre" });
}
```

}

When im debuggin i get the message: Uncaught ReferenceError: Operadores_lst is not defined

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbVJp.jpg)

This is the header code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<script src="ctrlCuentasOperadores.aspx.js?v=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(Inicializar);
</script>
```

Im working on VStudio 2013 C#

Comment: Do not use tags that are not related to your question. What is the meaning of C# here?

Comment: Where did you define/ initialize the `Operadores_lst` variable ?

Comment: You aren't explain what `Operadores_lst` belongs to... I think you're either not initializing it or not assigning it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shyju and Tetsuya, i found the error it was not declared the Operadores_lst for that reason i was receiving the error Uncaught ReferenceError: Operadores_lst is not defined. But i could resolve it thank you for your kind help.